# Can mathematics be constructed from logic?

Tags: logic, foundations

This may be a rather naive question in this day and age, but has mathematics been reduced to logic? In other words, can all of mathematics be constructed from logic?  My understanding is that Russell and Whitehead attempted to show that math could be derived from logic, but their attempt failed.  But that was over 100 years ago, so maybe things have changed.

Comment: I think it really depends what you mean. If you mean semantically - of course, logic is a branch of Mathematics (where we formally define "axiom", "proposition", "proof", etc etc)

Comment: What does "mathematics" mean, for you? If you consider that "mathematics" is just a game consisting in writing sentences respecting some rules, then you could say that "logic" is the set of rules. In this sense, "mathematics" are not constructed on anything; they're just characters written on paper.

Comment: This is not a mathematical question. It is crucially dependent on what you mean (a) by "mathematics" and (b) by "logic" and so it belongs on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com. (Just don't get me started on your statement about Russell and Whitehead's work ....)

Comment: Only the logical parts of mathematics can be constructed from logic. To construct the illogical parts, you need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Immanuel Kant seems to have believed that the mathematical truths that can be known extended beyond what deductive reasoning alone can prove.  It was controversial at the time because Liebnitz famously said otherwise,  but in the perspective of modern foundations of mathematics it seems to me well known and understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Practically all of mathematics is formalized as a theory of [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) in [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) using the axioms of [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

Comment: You mean "can be" formalised, not "is" formalised. And popular subjects like category theory and universal algebra give ZFC a rough time.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose "practically all" is a stretch, but hopefully this answer at least helps the asker clarify his question. Re "can be" vs. "is", would you not say that most mathematical objects *are* defined as sets (and most theorems *are* proved from ZFC), albeit indirectly? I wanted to emphasize that this isn't just something that we imagine might be possible but something that is actually done.

Comment: The crux would seem to be whether the ZFC axioms are considered "logic" (first-order logic certainly is).

Comment: Something like [Birkhoff's HSP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Birkhoff's_theorem) is hard to formalise satisfactorily within the straitjacket of a set theory (like ZFC) without classes.

Comment: (I should add that my very non-expert impression is that, at least in terms of how Logicism has traditionally been thought about, the answer is "no". The ZFC axioms are miles and miles away from what is considered to be "logic.")

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: the ZF axioms look very like logic if you connect predicates with the sets they denote and allow quantification over predicates ... Oh, I seem to be reinventing the *Principia*! It has been reinvented much more successfully, e.g., in modern [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory).

Answer (score 1):

While the answer to your question must depend upon your presuppositions concerning both logic and mathematics, there are some pragmatic considerations which seem independent. Logic demands ontology. The received views incorporate ontology under the guise of "self-identity" which declares the so-called law of identity to be axiomatic. From where does this presupposition actually arise? It is the consequence of bias against infinite regress.

This question applies to the distinction between comprehensionalist set theory and the category-theoretic notion of set because the latter relies upon inclusion, and, inclusion is interpreted as "second-order" by proponents of comprehensionalist set theory. As second-order logic is considered problematic, the comprehensionalist will reject the foundational import of the latter. This is explicit in the comparison of Dedekind's work and Peano's introduction of a symbol for membership. Russell points this out initially; you can find its modern account in Potter's book on set theory and its philosophy.

The comprehensionalist, however, relies on a dubious account of mathematics. The so-called crisis in geometry motivating the arithmetization of mathematics had actually been a crisis only for those who held unwarranted beliefs about geometry and material reality. Arithmetization can then be understood as replacing an unwarranted belief about geometry and material reality with an unwarranted belief about arithmetic and material reality. Both fall under unwarranted belief about mathematics and reality.

Formalism provides a means of distancing this problem from the practice of mathematics. But, it is not innocent . Hilbert promoted formalism to support the use of mathematics for applications. The idea of formalist  mathematics as a mere game of symbols has a different origin that conflates Hilbert's formal axiomatics with his metamathematical approach. Following the notion of sensible a priori intuition introduced by Kant, Hilbert simply restricted it to the sensible impressions of marks made on a page.

The problem with the modern account of formalist mathematics is that the dichotomy between syntax and semantics does not address the applicability of mathematics. This is because neither addresses the relationship between language and the users of language. A proper term for this comes from Carnap's response to the extreme syntactic nature of his early work. Namely, pragmatics.

Pragmatics enters in to your question because of how the teaching of geometry had been deprecated in favor of logic at the end of the nineteenth century in many places. Regardless of rhetoric on the part of logicians, most people learn about logical connectives through naive geometric incidence from Venn diagrams. The idea behind membership relating individuals to classes in logic is not geometric incidence.

So, now you have a problem because pragmatics is ignored.

Now consider "self-identity" in relation to 'true' and 'false'. If one is provided with symbols representing truth objects different from the natural language words that carry pragmatic import, how shall the truth value constants be assigned? Max Black wrote a paper on the problem of assigning names to a symmetric configuration.

You will find yourself involved in an infinite regress.

Comment: Observations like "logic demands ontology" are way out of the scope of MSE.